# Element overflowing parent and scroll not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox

I'm not a css expert and I don't understand why my right-bottom divs don't work as expected.

I'm using a jquery extension (jquery-resizable) to resize some panels and I want that one of my last divs `.overflow-container` (level 2) keeps the size of his parent div `#resizable-panel-right-bottom` (level 1). It is ok but if I set a high value in the inner div `.overflow-content` (level 3) for the height, then the height for `.overflow-container` (level 2) isn't correct anymore.

Here I have a draft on [codepen](https://codepen.io/jin-k/pen/PgRKJo) of what I want to do:

```
#resizable-panel-right-bottom {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    min-height: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.overflow-container {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  background: aqua;
  overflow: scroll; /*should be "overflow: auto" I know*/
}
.overflow-content {
  height: 1000px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: pink;
}
```

The goal is to have a jquery datatable (from datatables.net) in the last div.

Actually I'm using this JS libraries:
[jQuery 3.3.1](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js)
[bootstrap 4](https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js)
[jquery-resizable](https://rawgit.com/RickStrahl/jquery-resizable/master/src/jquery-resizable.js)

And [bootstrap 4 styles](https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css)

Answer (score 0):

You need to reconfigure your height definitions.

The problem is that you've scattered `height: 100%` throughout your HTML structure. However, for percentage heights to be recognized properly, they must have a defined height on the parent.

Flex heights, like you have with `flex-basis: auto` in some places, are not always sufficient.

See:

- [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)
- [Chrome / Safari not filling 100% height of flex parent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276)

Also see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow):

> In order for `overflow` to have an effect, the block-level container must have either a set height (`height` or `max-height`) or `white-space` set to `nowrap`.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure I totally understood your answer, but the `height: 100%` point showed me the correct way to fix this (I hope): Solution on [codepen](https://codepen.io/jin-k/pen/PgBbZM)